# angular datatable with deferred rendering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatable

I am using the angular datatables from here - https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome

I have about 4,000 rows that I am loading, and using the datatable this way it's extremely slow.

My first option is to use ajax loading of few hundreds every time, but the heavy lifting is actually in the rendering process and not fetching the data from the server.

I saw that there is an option to do a deferred rendering but it's some how not available in angular. Do you guys have any idea how to use it with angular?

This is snippet of my code -

**HTML**

```
<table datatable="ng" role="grid" data-page-length="50"> </table>
```

**JS**

```
only loads the datatable.js code
```

I would like to add to the HTML / JS an option for deferred rendering

any ideas?
Thanks a lot.

I am loading the data table

Comment: Look into Server side processing. For this library there seems to be this https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/serverSideProcessing

Comment: This solution is using the server. Is seems that what making the page slow is the actual rendering, not bringing the data from the server. What I am looking for is a way to render only the first 50 rows on page load, and them on demand (search / sort) render the rest. something like lazy rendering.

Comment: Ya, but this way you can only get / render what is needed for each page, nothing more noting less.

Comment: The bottleneck is `datatable="ng"`, it is extremely ineffective - you should let dataTables render the table _then_ you can use `deferRender`.

Comment: Thanks David, can you please elaborate on the solution you offer? How do I load my datatable not like datatable="ng"? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I have done something like this ... load initially some 50 rows and on scrollbar reaching the  bottom, call database fetch more 50 and add to the existing 50.

Every time scrollbar reaches bottom, hit database and fetch more 50.

This would work.